# Facebook Connect button doesn't always work

Tags: php, authentication, facebook

Some times the facebook connect button works fine, goes on to the next page.

But at some times it doesn't. It seems to do so at random.. with no apparent reason.

Basically what happens when there is a problem is as follows:

You click on the button, a pop up to login to facebook appears. So far so good.

Then you insert your facebook credentials, and enter/ click on the ok button, and...

the facebook pop up dissappears (as it should), but instead of the next page, the previous page with the facebook connect button reappears.

Then when clicking on the facebook connect button the facebook login popup appears for a second and dissappears, and we remain on the original page where the facebook connect button is.

What should I check? What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this reliably enough to debug? Do you see any script errors in your browser? (You may have to open developer tools console or similar.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce, but it happens so I will def see it again. I am using firefox with firebug. I tried clicking on script and enabling it, in console it is now set to "break on all errors"; It says in the console "enabling javascript debugger to support JavaScriptTool"; and now I am unable to click on the facebook connect button at all (it is not clickable).

Comment: Hi, this time it let me click on the connect button and login, but it had the following in the console: `uncaught exception: Error: ÜÐ àÙêàÔ Ü¾<https://www.facebook.com> ÔèéÐÔ ÜçÑÜ Ðê ÔÞÐäÙÙß Proxy.InstallTrigger`